# Infinitiv im Präsens oder im Perfekt? ... – wie es ihm gelang, so viele Sprachen zu beherrschen

Tags: tense

Infinitiv im Präsens oder im Perfekt?

> Sterbend nahm er mit sich ins Grab sein Geheimnis – wie es ihm gelang, so viele Sprachen zu beherrschen.

oder

> Sterbend nahm er mit sich ins Grab sein Geheimnis – wie es ihm gelang, so viele Sprachen beherrscht zu haben.

Comment: Der Beispielsatz hat mehrere Schwächen: *sterbend* trägt nichts zur Bedeutung bei, *mit ins Grab nehmen* setzt das voraus. Schlimmer: noch *sterbend* ist ein Partizip Präsens, während des Sterbens passiert aber gar nichts. Auch der einzelne  Gedankenstrich überzeugt mich nicht, das sollte eher ein Nebensatz zu *Geheimnis* sein, oder ein Einschub mit zwei Gedankenstrichen.

Answer (score 1):

> Sterbend nahm er mit sich ins Grab sein Geheimnis – wie es ihm gelang, so viele Sprachen zu beherrschen.

Diese Variante sagt aus, dass es ihm (erst) sterbend gelang, viele Sprachen zu beherrschen. Das ist aber sicher nicht gemeint. Man kann davon ausgehen, dass ihm das schon vorher (irgendwie) gelungen war.

Der erste Teil muss also heißen:

> Sterbend nahm er mit sich ins Grab sein Geheimnis - wie es ihm **gelungen war**, so viele Sprachen ...

Wie es hinten weitergeht, hängt davon ab, ob er die Sprachen zum Zeitpunkt seines Sterbens immer noch beherrscht hat. Wenn er beispielsweise vor seinem Sterben schon einige Zeit an Demenz gelitten und darüber die Fähigkeit verloren hatte, die Sprachen zu beherrschen, dann könnte man durchaus sagen:

> Sterbend nahm er mit sich ins Grab sein Geheimnis - wie es ihm **gelungen war**, so viele Sprachen **beherrscht zu haben**.

Ansonsten, wenn er also die Sprachen bis zuletzt beherrscht hat, war es ihm vorher (irgendwie) gelungen, diese Fähigkeit zum Zeitpunkt des Sterbens zu haben. Und dann sollte es heißen:

> Sterbend nahm er mit sich ins Grab sein Geheimnis - wie es ihm **gelungen war**, so viele Sprachen **zu beherrschen**.

Vielleicht wird es an einem anderen Beispiel noch deutlicher:

> Selbst sterbend gelang es ihm noch, alle Anwesenden davon zu überzeugen, niemals Unrecht getan zu haben.

Dagegen:

> Sterbend nahm er mit sich ins Grab sein Geheimnis - wie es ihm gelang, lächelnd von der Welt Abschied zu nehmen.

Answer (score 0):

> Sterbend nahm er mit sich ins Grab sein Geheimnis – wie es ihm
>   gel**ungen war**, so viele Sprachen zu beherrschen.

This plusquamperfekt is important. Then the present infinitve is natural.

The words are not really well chosen here to express a learning process, unless you want to make it sound like he made a deal with some supernatural power.

> ? How had he succeeded in mastering so many languages.
>
> ??? How did he succeed in having mastered so many languages.

Comment: Wie würdest du das denn umformulieren?

Comment: Würde deiner Meinung nach auch der Infinitiv Perfekt gehen?

Comment: Infinitiv Perfekt scheint mir falsch, das würde sich auf einen Zeitpunkt vor das Gelingen beziehen. "Ich bedauerte,  x eingeladen zu haben." . Dass er nun tot ist und nichts mehr beherrscht, spielt hier keine Rolle.  "...so viele Sprachen kennengelernt zu haben".

Comment: @rastafile: die Frage ist in Deutsch gestellt, da sind deutsche Antworten üblich - vice versa für Englisch gestellte Fragen.

Answer (score 0):

Der Bezugspunkt der Zeiten in diesem Satz ist:

> Er nahm mit ins Grab. (Präteritum)

Nun ist etwas passiert, *bevor* er sich im Grab wiederfand. Das erfordert also das Plusquamperfekt:

> Es war ihm gelungen. (Plusquamperfekt)

Fraglich ist nun das Verhältnis von *gelingen* und *beherrschen*. Bezugspunkt ist hier wiederum *gelingen*:

> *Es war ihm gelungen, (davor) so viele Sprachen beherrscht zu haben:* Er beherrschte sie nicht mehr, als es ihm gelungen war (vorzeitig)
>
> *Es war ihm gelungen, so viele Sprachen zu beherrschen:* Er beherrschte sie, als es ihm gelungen war (gleichzeitig, also als er noch lebte)

Richtig ist somit: *Sterbend nahm er mit sich ins Grab sein Geheimnis – wie es ihm gelang, so viele Sprachen zu beherrschen.* Gelingen und beherrschen sind untereinander gleichzeitig, zusammen jedoch vorzeitig zum Mit-ins-Grab-nehmen.